# Big PDF to JPEG Conversion with ImageMagick returns 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

My code converts PDF file pages into JPEG images once uploaded, and it all goes fine when working on light PDFs (not many images and effects, while the number of pages is no more than 40-50 on average).  But when file is heavier, I get a **"500 Internal Error"**. The PDF has been uploaded and pages have been converted up to the break point.

My code:

```
$foldername = str_replace('.','',preg_replace('/\s+/', '', microtime()));
mkdir("./mag_thumbs/".$foldername, 0755, TRUE);
try
{
    $compression_type = Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG; 
    $im = new imagick();
    $im->setResolution(250,250);
    $im->readimage($pdf_path); 
    $pdf_count = $im->getNumberImages();
    $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
    $im->flattenImages();    
    $im->setImageCompression($compression_type); 
    $im->setImageCompressionQuality(40); 
    $im->writeImages('./mag_thumbs/'.$foldername.'/page.jpg',true); 
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy();
}
catch(Exception $e){ /* SOME TROUBLESHOOTING CODE */ }
```

Am I supposed to expand servers' time out? Any other better solution?

Comment: How long does a failed conversion take? Are you doing this in a web request? If you are, and if conversion takes more than a few seconds, move it to an offline process, like a cron or a job queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter these lines above your code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 10000);//you can change this limit
ini_set("memory_limit", "6400M");//you can change this limit
```